# How to set the port portion for same origin policy?

Tags: javascript, web, same-origin-policy

I know that `document.domain` sets the domain portion of the same origin policy. How to set the port portion for the same origin policy?

**Details**

I can use `document.domain` to set the domain portion. This sets the port portion to `null`. By default the document inside iframe sets the port portion to 80/443. So the same origin policy fails and the parent JS will not be able to access the iframe content document object. So is there a way to set the port portion of the same origin policy in the parent JS?

Comment: perhaps you want to use `globalThis.origin` instead of the `document.domain`?

Comment: `globalThis.origin` will not help set the origin domain/port

Answer (score 0):

From the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy):

> The port number is checked separately by the browser. Any call to
> document.domain, including document.domain = document.domain, causes
> the port number to be overwritten with null. Therefore, one cannot
> make company.com:8080 talk to company.com by only setting
> document.domain = "company.com" in the first. It has to be set in both
> so their port numbers are both null.

Comment: I have read this. but I do not have access to the page I am opening inside iframe. without setting document.domain in the page inside iframe, how do I achieve it?